# Plotting a slice of a multivariable SymPy expression

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

I am trying to plot an expression with multiple variables. I want to specify numerical values for all the symbols except one, and plot the function with respect to that one variable.

The expression is shown here:
[image]

I tried plotting using this method:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as smp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
smp.init_printing() 
dP_single,dP_parallel, Q,mu,L_filter,L_cake,K_filter,K_cake=smp.symbols('dP_single,dP_parallel, Q,mu,L_filter,L_cake,K_filter,K_cake')

Eq1=smp.Eq((-Q*mu*(L_filter+L_cake)/(K_filter+K_cake))-dP_single,0)
Eq2=smp.Eq((-(Q/2)*mu*(L_filter+(L_cake/2))/(K_filter+K_cake))-dP_parallel,0)
sol=smp.solve([Eq1,Eq2],[dP_single,dP_parallel])
display(sol)
Eq2=smp.Eq((1/4)*(-L_cake*Q*mu-2*L_filter*Q*mu)*dP_single/(-L_cake*Q*mu-L_filter*Q*mu)-dP_parallel,0).simplify()
display(Eq2)
sol2=smp.solve(Eq2,dP_parallel)
display(sol2[0].simplify())

def percent_dP_single(L_cake_):
    percent_dPsingle=smp.N(sol2[0].subs({'dP_single':1,'L_cake':L_cake_,'L_filter':.005}))
    return percent_dPsingle 

L_cake=np.linspace(0,.01,200)
plt.plot(L_cake,percent_dP_single(L_cake))
```

I get the following error:

```
x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (200,) and (1,)
```

Comment: please, post a complete reproducible example. Right now, we can't execute any code, hence we can't make proper suggestions.

Comment: I'd suggest changing `plt.plot(L_cake,percent_dP_single(L_cake))` to `plt.plot(L_cake, [percent_dP_single(lc) for lc in L_cake])`

Comment: Or, wrap your `percent_dP_single` in a [`numpy.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use the NumPy [`vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) class, so that you can call your `percent_dP_single` function (which currently wants a single scalar value) with a NumPy array as the argument:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as smp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
smp.init_printing() 
dP_single,dP_parallel, Q,mu,L_filter,L_cake,K_filter,K_cake=smp.symbols('dP_single,dP_parallel, Q,mu,L_filter,L_cake,K_filter,K_cake')

Eq1=smp.Eq((-Q*mu*(L_filter+L_cake)/(K_filter+K_cake))-dP_single,0)
Eq2=smp.Eq((-(Q/2)*mu*(L_filter+(L_cake/2))/(K_filter+K_cake))-dP_parallel,0)
sol=smp.solve([Eq1,Eq2],[dP_single,dP_parallel])
display(sol)
Eq2=smp.Eq((1/4)*(-L_cake*Q*mu-2*L_filter*Q*mu)*dP_single/(-L_cake*Q*mu-L_filter*Q*mu)-dP_parallel,0).simplify()
display(Eq2)
sol2=smp.solve(Eq2,dP_parallel)
display(sol2[0].simplify())

# add vectorize decorator
@np.vectorize
def percent_dP_single(L_cake_):
    percent_dPsingle=smp.N(sol2[0].subs({'dP_single':1,'L_cake':L_cake_,'L_filter':.005}))
    return percent_dPsingle 

L_cake=np.linspace(0,.01,200)
plt.plot(L_cake,percent_dP_single(L_cake))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options:

Here is the common code:

```py
import numpy as np
import sympy as smp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
smp.init_printing() 
dP_single,dP_parallel, Q,mu,L_filter,L_cake,K_filter,K_cake=smp.symbols('dP_single,dP_parallel, Q,mu,L_filter,L_cake,K_filter,K_cake')

Eq1=smp.Eq((-Q*mu*(L_filter+L_cake)/(K_filter+K_cake))-dP_single,0)
Eq2=smp.Eq((-(Q/2)*mu*(L_filter+(L_cake/2))/(K_filter+K_cake))-dP_parallel,0)
sol=smp.solve([Eq1,Eq2],[dP_single,dP_parallel])
display(sol)
Eq2=smp.Eq((1/4)*(-L_cake*Q*mu-2*L_filter*Q*mu)*dP_single/(-L_cake*Q*mu-L_filter*Q*mu)-dP_parallel,0).simplify()
display(Eq2)
sol2=smp.solve(Eq2,dP_parallel)
display(sol2[0].simplify())

def percent_dP_single(L_cake_):
    percent_dPsingle=smp.N(sol2[0].subs({'dP_single':1,'L_cake':L_cake_,'L_filter':.005}))
    return percent_dPsingle
```

#### 1. Use Matplotlib directly.

In order to plot a symbolic expression, it is best to first convert it to a numerical function which can then be evaluated with Numpy. Take a look at the function [`lambdify`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#sympy.utilities.lambdify.implemented_function):

```py
func = smp.lambdify([dP_single, L_cake, L_filter], sol2[0])
L_cake_num = np.linspace(0,.01,200)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(L_cake_num, func(1, L_cake_num, 0.005))
# note that I provided arguments ordered as specified in the lambdify call
```

[image]

#### 2. Use sympy plotting

Here, the `lambdify` step is done automatically by the plotting module. All you need to do is to provide the appropriate symbolic expression.

Because you know the values of two parameters, you can substitute them into the symbolic expression, and let the plotting module do the rest:

```py
from sympy import plot
plot(sol2[0].subs({dP_single: 1, L_filter: 0.005}), (L_cake, 0, 0.01))
```

[image]

#### 3. Playing with widgets

Seems like you are playing with parameters, maybe you would like to play with widgets too? Here is a more advanced [plotting module for SymPy](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

The following code needs to be run inside a Jupyter notebook:

```py
from spb import plot
%matplotlib widget

params = {
    dP_single: (1, 0, 2), # (default_value, min_value, max_value)
    L_filter: (0.005, 0, 0.1)
}
plot(sol2[0], (L_cake, 0, 0.01), params=params)
```

[image]